# React: does it cost extra memory when passing object as prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to optimize my React app's memory usage here.
Want to understand what happens when I pass a big object as prop to a child component, am I doubling the memory usage of my app?
Ultimately, what counts as the memory that a component may consume.

Comment: The short answer is, no. The longer answer is that a reference to the object (rather than the object itself) is passed to your component. That means the recipient component is "looking at the same bit of memory containing object data", rather than taking a complete copy (ie doubling total memory usage).

Comment: What leads you to think your app has a memory usage problem to begin with?

Comment: It also depends on how you are passing the object. If you are using the spread operator on the object when passing as prop then the object is being recreated and will take up more memory.

Answer (score 1):

No. Since, you are simply passing the object reference as a prop to the child component, there is no duplicate of that object saved on the memory. The child component would still be referencing to the same memory location as the parent component.